# If a morphism is an isomorphism on all infinitesimal neighborhoods of the special fiber, is it an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X, Y$ be finite type schemes over a complete local noetherian ring $A$, and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be an $A$-morphism. If $f_n: X_n \rightarrow Y_n$, with $X_n = X \times_A A/\mathfrak{m}_A^n$, $Y_n = Y \times_A A/\mathfrak{m}_A^n$, is an isomorphism for all $n$, does it follow that $f$ is an isomorphism?

More generally, is it true that $X \mapsto (X_n)_n, f \mapsto (f_n)_n$ defines a fully faithful functor from finite type $A$-schemes to inductive systems of $A/\mathfrak{m}_A^n$-schemes?

In FGA Explained, this is proved for the case that $X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} \ A$ is proper. In my setting, this is probably not true. However, I do know that $X$ and $Y$ are both $A$-flat (actually, I can even assume that $A$ is a $k$-algebra for a field $k$ and $X, Y$ are of the form $X_0 \times_k A, Y_0 \times_k A$ for finite type $k$-schemes $X_0, Y_0$).

Comment: In general this is false. For example, your $A$ could be a dvr, $X,Y$ schemes supported on the generic point of $A$. Then $X_n,Y_n$ are empty sets (which is avoided in the proper case).

Comment: This example can't be finite type though, right? (By Chevalley)

Comment: For a dvr $A$, the fraction field is of finite type, since it is just $A[x]/(\pi x-1)$ where $\pi$ is the generator of the maximal ideal of $\pi$.

Comment: Oh right - I find I often forget that some facts I know about constructible sets only apply to varieties (or Jacobson schemes). So this example is finite type and also flat. Weird.